# How to send readable part of mp4 while recording it

Tags: android, post, video, send, mediarecorder

I'm working on an app that records video in background and sends it to server in parts by reading bytes and storing them in byte array. For now algorithm is pretty simple:

1. start recording;
2. reading part of video file to byte array;
3. send byte array via POST (with help of retrofit).

Problem occurs if connection somehow interrupts and last part isn't sent. Server just can't make readable video file as moov atom would be written only after recording stops. My question - is it possible some how to make complete video files from byte array parts or any other way? I can change video codec if it would solve the problem.
p.s. I can only send data via POST.
p.p.s I can't change something on server side including streaming video directly to server.

Comment: Don't use MP4. Use flv, webm, ts, or fragmented MP4

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can I make appropriate slit of, for example, webm. And one more question - how can I configure mediarecorder to record fragmented mp4?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I decided to record small chunks of video in recursive way. Next solution is suitable for first version of Camera API. If you're using Camera2 or something else - you can try to use same algorithm.

In service class that records video make sure that mediarecorder is configured next way:

```
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
    //or
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(10000);
```

Then you need to implement setOnInfoListener interface next way:

```
mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                            //Use next condition if you decided to use max file size
                           //if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)

                            stopRecording();
                            setRecordingStatus(false);
                            startRecording(surfaceHolder);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Don't forget to pass surfaceHolder instance for next iteration otherwise you can get "Application lost surface" error.
 
Next thing you need to do is declare FileObserver in onCreate method:

```
FileObserver fileObserver = new FileObserver(pathToFolder, FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE) {
//FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE mask means that this observer would be triggered when it receive end of writing to file system event
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                //here path is name of file (with extension) but not the full path to file
                    if (event == FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE && path.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    String name = String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(path.substring(0, path.length() - 4)) / 1000);
                    sendNewVideo(pathToFolder + "/" + path, name);
                }

            }
};
```

In onStartCommand method:

```
fileObserver.startWatching();
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for us, but the camera stops recording while it's saving the video fragments. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Check if you're releasing camera when stopping record